# How to use boost::aio::async_connect with lambda

Tags: c++11, boost, lambda, boost-asio, beast-websockets

I want to reliaze how to use boost::aio::async_connect with lambda.
Boost version 1.68

It's really strange that I could use std::bind but not lambda.
If I use std::bind, it work.
But when I use lambda, it buillt failed, and said "IteratorConnectHandler type requirements not met.

std::bind version (worked)

```
void SslClient::connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type results) {
    auto sp = shared_from_this();
    boost::asio::async_connect(ws->next_layer().next_layer(),
        results.begin(),
        results.end(),
        std::bind(
            on_connect,
            std::placeholders::_1)

    );
}
```

lambda version (not worked)

```
void SslClient::connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type results) {
    auto sp = shared_from_this();
    boost::asio::async_connect(ws->next_layer().next_layer(),
        results.begin(),
        results.end(),
            [&, sp](boost::system::error_code ec) {
               if (ec) {
                   return;
               }
               ws->next_layer().async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                                                [&, sp](boost::system::error_code ec1) {
                                                    handShake(ec);
                                                });
        }


    );
}
```

So how to use lambda here?

Comment: Please post a full error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call [async_connect](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect/overload3.html) with pair of iterators, so your lambda should meet [iterator connect handler requirements](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/IteratorConnectHandler.html). As second parameter you have to pass *connected endpoint*.

```
boost::asio::async_connect(ws->next_layer().next_layer(),
    results.begin(),
    results.end(),
        [&, sp](  boost::system::error_code ec,
                  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it) 
           {
           if (ec) {
               return;
           }
           //...
```

To be consistent with reference you should also fix bind version. `on_connect` should also take `iterator` as second param.

Your current `bind` version compiles and works, but when asynchronous operation initiated by `async_connect` is completed, functor created by `bind` is called with only `error_code`, you cannot access `endpoint`. You can modify bind so that it takes `on_connect` without any arguments.

```
void on_connect(){}

boost::asio::async_connect(ws->next_layer().next_layer(),
        results.begin(), results.end(), std::bind(on_connect)); // compiles fine
```

this also compiles, but when handler is called neither `error_code` nor `endpoint` can be accessed. (Yes it is a bit strange that you are not getting compiler errors when using `bind` which inform that requirements of handler are not fulfilled. I don't know where this disagreement between lambda and bind comes from.)